# Visual Studio pre-link event triggers twice

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build, msbuild

Sorry the problem is probably not reproducible by others, but still maybe someone had it before or has a clue what might be going on...

I have a C++ solution in visual studio 2015, community edition.
There are 3 project: a lib, a test app for the lib and the actual application that uses the lib. The final app has a build dependency on the test app and custom pre-link step, so it executes unit tests on each build:

[image]

Both test app and the real app are console applications.
Once I press F7 to build the solution, I see the following:

1. the lib builds (as expected)
2. the test app builds and links (as expected)
3. the test app is triggered and I can see it running in a console window, with window title exactly as in the custom build step **(this is not expected)**
4. the test app runs again, this time without the console window, instead I see its console output in VS Output window. (expected)
5. the real application builds and links (expected)

What's even more weird, step #3 doesn't happen always. I cannot figure out why and what's the rule.

Any clues anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was so annoying I've spent more time trying to figure out what's happening and finally noticed, that it's the antivirus....
This is the solution: [getavast.net/support/disable-cybercapture](http://getavast.net/support/disable-cybercapture)

Comment: Are you sure this is it? I'm having a similar problem and I don't have an antivirus...

Comment: Yes, in my case it was for sure that problem with the antivirus, but maybe there are other root causes for similar issues. Good luck debugging it... and let others know when you succeed.

Comment: Well I succeeded... except I noticed it completely randomly so I have no idea what caused it. Good luck to the next person debugging it indeed!!